# How can we display the parcel outlines or boundaries on the OpenStreetMap

Tags: mapbox-static-maps

I want to display parcel outlines or boundaries on the OpenStreetMap. But when I use OpenStreetMap dynamic map for address "10543 JERSEY RD, MILTON, FL,32583" (latitude: 30.620948, Longitude: -86.881137). It does not display any parcel outlines or boundaries. But some platforms like https://maps.mapwise.com/ display parcel outlines or boundaries on OpenStreetMap Map. So anyone can advise how I display parcel outlines or boundaries on any Static or dynamic map. (OpenStreetMap Maps, MapQuest Maps, Bing Maps, etc.).[image: image with parcel outlines]

Please advice. I am using the PHP framework Laravel to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: the background map is truly the OpenStreetMap, but the layer with boundaries does not come from OSM but rather from another source. Did you try exlporing the source code of the page?

Having said that, I need to add that OSM contains a lot of polygons (city boundaries, timezones, etc.) and you can explore them interactively. Have a look at this image: [image: screenshot]

If you open the map and click on the the "Query Features" button at bottom right, then click on the map and it will list all nearby and surrounding OSM elements at location of your click. I created this snapshot at [this location](https://www.openstreetmap.org/query?lat=30.62204&lon=-87.04295).